# Module parse failed: Unexpected token (React.js)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I wrote the frontend and backend part in the Mern stack project, but I got such an error during the api integration, how can I solve it?

```
   ./src/compenents/Post.js 78:25
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (78:25)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|           switch (_context.prev = _context.next) {
|             case 0:
>               if (!(post?._id && answer !== "")) {
|                 _context.next = 5;
|                 break;
```

Comment: What's is your complete code

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/68042245/6346643

Comment: I couldn't figure out which piece of code the problem was from. I checked post.js and there is no piece of code that starts with the switch. I also couldn't find which file this piece of code is in. i will check the link :)